# Adding static dropdown for postal codes in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i am working wordpress site. Can any one tell me how to add static dropdown for postal codes.As i need to add only particular location for delivery.And need to check whether the location entered by the customer is available for delivery or not and display a message as the location is not available for delivery.

```
'postcode' => array(
            'label'        => __( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'     => true,
            'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
            'validate'     => array( 'postcode' ),
            'autocomplete' => 'postal-code',
            'priority'     => 90,
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add the static dropdown in woocommerce as in this format.

```
'postcode' => array(
            'label'        => __( 'Area ( Delivery only applicable for area locations listed below  ) ', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'     => true,
            'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
            'validate'     => array( 'postcode' ),
            'autocomplete' => 'postal-code',
            'priority'     => 90,
            'required'     => true,
            'type'         =>'select',
            'options'      =>array('opt1' => "Arekere", "Gottegere", "Billekhalli", "BTM Layout", "Puttenhalli", "Vijaya Bank Layout", "Hulimeavu", "JP Nagar", "Deverchekalli", "Kodichinalkalli", "Akshay Nagar", "DLF New Town", "SNN Raj Serenity")

        ),
```

Comment: Old response but was wondering if you encountered any issues after doing so. I've tried to replace the default text input with a dropdown (discouraged in the official docs since it's part of the core) but the shipping areas stopped working correctly after that.